# Ubuntu 11.04 fails to boot in Macbok

Tags: boot, system-installation, 11.04, macbook

After installing Ubuntu 11.4 in a Macbook 5,2 I get a blinking folder with a question mark at boot.

The installation was successful erasing the entire drive, but the computer fails to boot Ubuntu, I launched the Live USB and inserted these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr -o 0
```

Also modified the `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=noncq"`

And inserted this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

However it returns:

```
cannot stat aufs
```

The blinking folder is still present.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 has reached End of Support in 2012. Please use a newer version like 14.04.

Comment: It is quite hilarious when people close questions after they have been already answered and acepted. There are better things to do with your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 has reached End of Support in 2012. I recommend [Ubuntu MATE 14.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/) for this laptop. It will run in a extremely fluent way. Here you're a screenshot:

[image: Ubuntu MATE Screenshot]

Comment: I did my research before installing 11.04, [it should work right out of the box](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook5-2/Natty).

There are reports of [14 having compatibility issues](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook5-2) therefore I decided not to use it. I will install it and return to you before calling it a day.

Comment: It did work! I had to manually install the wireless driver [following this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). It was a bit confusing but finally worked.